# splunk join 2 search queries

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am writing a splunk query to find out top exceptions that are impacting client. So I have 2 queries, one is client logs and another server logs query. Joined both of them using a common field, these are production logs so I am changing names of it. I am trying to find top 5 failures that are impacting client. below is my query.

```
index=pirs sourcetype=client-* env=* (type=Error error_level=fatal) error_level=fatal serviceName=FailedServiceEndpoint | table _time,serviceName,xab,endpoint,statusCode | join left=L right=R where L.xab = R.xab [search index=zirs sourcetype=server-*  | rex mode=sed field=span_name "s#\..*$##" | search span_success = false spanName=FailedServiceEndpoint |  table _time,spanName,xab] | chart count over L.serviceName
```

I explicitly mentioned a service name in here, In the final query there wont be service name, because we need top 5 failures that are impacting client.

This query provides me with service name and count, I also need other columns like endpoint name, httpStatusCode I am not sure how to do that and also if there is anything refactoring required for splunk query?

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd use of `join`.  I don't see that particular syntax documented, but apparently it works for you.

To get more fields, use `stats` instead of `chart`.

```
| stats count, values(endpointName) as endpointName, values(httpStatusCode) as httpStatusCode by serviceName
```

Comment: Joining splunk queries using common field is a usecase of join, right?

Comment: Yes, but `join left=L right=R where L.xab = R.xab` is not.  I expected something like `join type=left xab`.

Comment: Common field in both queries has different name, so I used in this way. I am representing as xab here, but it’s a different name.

Comment: Rename the field within the subsearch so it matches the field in the main search.